# Directive not rendering until any DOM change is made

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is pretty strange. I have an Angular directive that is part of an ng-repeat, and there are no elements in the ng-repeat's source array until a specific action is performed by the user.

Once that action is performed, the array is populated correctly and the element is added to the DOM -- but doesn't actually render. On literally any DOM change -- altering any CSS property of any element on the pages, resizing the page, anything -- the element appears as expected.

Not sure what code would actually be useful to help diagnose this problem, but I'm happy to provide anything relevant.

Other relevant information: Works as expected in Safari, using Ionic framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough that the user perform an action, Angular must *find out* that the user has done so.  You are supposed to inform it by calling `$digest()` but as that can fail if you are already in a digest call, I just call `$timeout()`.